# Bolzano weierstrass theorem for bounded sets in $E_n$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am reading through mathematical analysis by Apostol,

The bolzano theorem for n-dimensional Euclidean spaces is provided as follows:

"If a bounded set S in $E_n$ contains infinitely many points, then there exists at least one point in $E_n$ which is an accumulation point of S".

Here is my attempted proof:

So $S \subset E_n$ with $\mathbf{x} \in E_n$, suppose an infinite open interval is denoted by $J_{\infty}=(-\infty, \infty)$ then we have $S \cap J_{\infty} = \mathbf{K}$ we assign $\mathbf{K}$ the set of infinitely many points.

Because S is bounded then we have $S \subset N(0;r)$ with some radius $r>0$. We have to show some $N(\mathbf{x})\subset \mathbf{K}$, suppose I assign each individual point in $\mathbf{K}$ the letter $k$, such that $\mathbf{K}=\{k_1, k_2, ...\}$

Then taking the difference of each point relative to $\mathbf{x}$, I have $\mathbf{Y}=\{|\mathbf{x}-k_1|,|\mathbf{x}-k_2|,|\mathbf{x}-k_3| \cdots\}$ for at least one of these differences, we get that they're not equal to $0$, this implies some $N(\mathbf{x}) \subset \mathbf{K}$, and so $\mathbf{x}$ is an accumulation point of S?

I am a first-timer at proving so please let me know how to improve this or whether it's totally wrong altogether!

Comment: I don't understand very well what do you mean by $S\cap J_{\infty}$. If $n>1$ this intersection is simply the empty set. Also the philosophy of your proof is wrong. You start with a generic point of $S$ and you try to prove it's an accumulation point withoout any restriction on $\mathbf{x}$. This can never work since not all points in $S$ are necessarily accumulation points.

Comment: If you really are a beginner in proving, then I suggest you start from simpler proofs. The proof(s) Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem are mostly non-trivial.

Comment: The theorem asserts that there exists a sequence $(s_j)$ in $S$ and $x \in E_n$ such that $s_j \to x$ as $j \to \infty$. I suggest you start with the case $n = 1$, and $S = [a, b]$. It's easy to reduce the general case to this one anyway.